# How to pass arguments to a function with one passed? (ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

There is a function with 3 arguments set by default:

```
function func( a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 ) {
    console.log(a, b, c);
}
```

How to pass arguments to a function with one passed?
For example:

```
func(10, , 30);
```

Comment: You can do `func(10,undefined,30)` but there may be a better way, so I'll let someone else answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `undefined`, which is the value for undefined variables for [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters):

> In JavaScript, parameters of functions default to `undefined`.

The default check works like

```
b = b !== undefined ? b : 2
```

```js
function func(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) {
    console.log(a, b, c);
}

func(10, undefined, 30);
```

Answer (score 4):

You could also pass an object and destructure it:

```
function func({a = 1, b = 2, c = 3}){
 console.log(a,b,c);
}

func({
 a:1,
 c:5
});
```

Comment: This is elegant. I like elegant stuff.

Comment: but it change the signature of the function.

Comment: @Nina does it? Isn't the signature still an object with 3 keys `{ a, b, c }`?

Comment: @JeremyThille, no the function has only one parameter, instead of three.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were answering to Khauri, not to Jonas. Sorry.

Comment: @Jonasw, the parameterlist has changed with an object instead of anonymous values which are not bound to property names.